# Animation not easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

i have some problem with my transitioning. here is the javascript/jquery

```js
function moveProgressBar(v, a) {
    var getPercent = v / 100;
    var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
    var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
    var animationLength = a;

    $('.progress-bar').stop().animate({
        left: progressTotal
        }, animationLength, function(){

        if (getPercent === 1) {

            $('.progress').css('height','auto');
            $('.progress_checkout').text('Proceed to checkout!');
        } else {
            $('.progress').css('height','2rem');
            $('.progress_checkout').text('');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.progress_checkout{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto 0;
    display: block; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.progress_checkout:hover{
   background-color: white;
   color: #C6DA80;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2rem;
}

.progress-wrap {
    background: #C6DA80;
    margin: 20px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.progress-bar {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="0">
    <a class="progress progress_checkout"></a>
    <div class="progress-bar progress"></div>
</div>
```

What i want to do is that when this progress bar is full display the text and make the bar bigger. It does that but the animation is instant instead of over 0.5s or so. I have tried it with addClass and removeClass and it does exactly the same. I've even added transition on ever element that it has possible contact with and it will still be instant.

> NOTE: If something seems missing please let me know because i might
>   have not pasted all the code. Though as far as I'm concerned this
>   should be everything related too the animations

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's animate uses it's own [easing parameter](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Unfortunately, only `swing` and `linear` are available

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the jQuery UI suite.

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing).

You have two options.

The first is [CSS3 Animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), with which you can time and combine multiple animations. So I would suggest switching back to classes and using CSS.

The second is using [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/), which has the following list of easing options:

```
linear
swing
_default
easeInQuad
easeOutQuad
easeInOutQuad
easeInCubic
easeOutCubic
easeInOutCubic
easeInQuart
easeOutQuart
easeInOutQuart
easeInQuint
easeOutQuint
easeInOutQuint
easeInExpo
easeOutExpo
easeInOutExpo
easeInSine
easeOutSine
easeInOutSine
easeInCirc
easeOutCirc
easeInOutCirc
easeInElastic
easeOutElastic
easeInOutElastic
easeInBack
easeOutBack
easeInOutBack
easeInBounce
easeOutBounce
easeInOutBounce
```

What you choose or prefer is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but this ended up being my fix. Using opacity and having the a tag contain " " avoided the sudden jump from the text insert making the transition smooth.

```
if (getPercent === 1) {

    $('.progress').animate({height: "4rem"}, 1000);
    $('.progress_checkout').text('Proceed to checkout!');
    $('.progress_checkout').animate({opacity: 1}, 800);
} else {
    $('.progress').animate({height: "2rem"}, 1000);
    $('.progress_checkout').text('&nbsp;');
    $('.progress_checkout').animate({opacity: 0}, 800);
}
```